# Parallel processing in dual core ARMv7 processor

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, neon

I am working on Zedboard which contains dual-core ARM A9 processors and runs Linux. The board communicates with an external I/O device.

I have two functions written in 'C' language, which I have to run in parallel.

One function calls a while loop and continuously dumps data to the external device and receives the processed data back into a memory pointer.

The other function reads the data from the pointer location creates a copy of it and does computationally intensive processes (such as FFT, signal alignment etc which is slow).

The external device needs data at 15 million samples per second. which I am able to achieve if I only run the first function and it takes about 70% of one ARM core. When I run both the functions both of the ARM cores reaches its limit and I find that I am not able to provide the data to the external device in the required sample speed.

Is there a way in which I can restrict both the functions in independent cores (it doesn't matter of the second function is slow but the performance of the first function can't be compromised) and still be able to share data between them?

I tried using OpenMP but it didn't work in achieving the required performance. I read about SCHED_SETAFFINITY but had a problem in understanding its implementation.

I have optimized each of my functions as much as I could using NEON constructs/libraries and the auto-vectorization feature of ARM processors.

Comment: You're probably memory or cache bound. Insert some no-ops in the fft thread.

Comment: Also did you try playing with priorities of the threads on which functions are to be run?

Comment: What's the fft size and input/output type? Are you sure you are using the best algorithm and lib? Are you working on SDR? Anyway, I've seen so many bad NEON implementations on the web that are straight unusable.

Comment: Yes, I am working on an SDR implementation. I am using FFT size of 2048. Since my input and output types are complex in nature, I am using two float32 arrays for storing both input and output which gets typecasted to int16 for ADC/DAC before transmitting and receiving. I am using Project Ne10 library for my signal processing implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You can set each separate thread to a different core with:

```
 int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid,size_t cpusetsize,cpu_set_t *mask);
```

From the man page:

> Description
>
> A process's CPU affinity mask determines the set of CPUs on which it is eligible to run. On a multiprocessor system, setting the CPU affinity mask can be used to obtain performance benefits. For example, by dedicating one CPU to a particular process (i.e., setting the affinity mask of that process to specify a single CPU, and setting the affinity mask of all other processes to exclude that CPU), it is possible to ensure maximum execution speed for that process. Restricting a process to run on a single CPU also avoids the performance cost caused by the cache invalidation that occurs when a process ceases to execute on one CPU and then recommences execution on a different CPU.

But if your code has hard data relations between input and output thread, multithreading can be slower as single core usage! This is hardly related to the memory/cache and especially on arm on all the bridges between core/memory/cache and external bus systems. You should play around with the priority, affinity and maybe other parameters as well.

BTW: "15 million samples per second" and FFT with IO on 1 GHZ Arm with Linux in parallel. Wow! Hot stuff ;)

Comment: Okay Sir, I will try with setting thread priorities and will let you know the results

Comment: I suppose he's working on SDR (software defined radio) given to the data size and requirements. 15M samples/second isn't much.

Comment: Yes, Sir, 15.36MSps is the most basic which I have to achieve, I have to finally increase it to 61.44MSps but the issue is with the processing power of Arm processor in Zedboard.

Comment: Sir, Even after restricting the functions to their independent cores, I was not able to achieve the performance may be because of the 600MHz dual-Arm A9 processors. However, I have now changed the system and used another processor to share the high computational task, connected via ethernet